# How can I create a new object in a loop in java?

Tags: java, loops, object

I have an ArrayList of String named "info" and each string holds the information about an instance of my class Student.
I try converting the Arraylist into an array and then parsing it using split method.

```
String[] Stringinfo = new String[info.size()];
Stringinfo = info.toArray(Stringinfo);
```

after I parse each line I try to make a new object in my for loop and adding it to the Students ArrayList. What happens is that every time I create this new object Student, the other objects which were added to Students ArrayList before, are all changed to this new object.

```
String[] temp;
        for(int i = 1; i < LineCount + 1 ; i++)
        {
            temp = Stringinfo[i].split(" ");
            Student s = new Student(Integer.parseInt(temp[0]), Integer.parseInt(temp[1]), Integer.parseInt(temp[2]), Integer.parseInt(temp[3]), Integer.parseInt(temp[4]));
            Students.add(s);
        }
```

I tried printing Students in different points and everthing is alright until the new object is created. 
At any time all the objects have the same attribute values as the last object created.

this is the Student class constructor:

```
public Student(int certif, int class_id, int ave, int i, int a)
{
    certification_num = certif;
    class_id = class;
    average_point = ave;
    student_id = i;
    age = a;
}
```

I searched a lot but couldn't find an answer. Sorry if the answer is obvious I am new to Java.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Edit:

```
public class Student{

    public Student(){}
     public Student(int certif, int class, int ave, int i, int a)
    {
        certification_num = certif;
        class_id = class;
        average_point = ave;
        student_id = i;
        age = a;
    }


    public static int get_certification_num(){
        return certification_num;
    }

    public static int get_class_id(){
        return class_id;
    }

    public static int get_average_point(){
        return average_point;
    }

    public static int get_id(){
        return student_id;
    }

    public static int get_age(){
        return age;
    }

    private static int certification_num;
    private static int class_id;
    private static int age;
    private static int node_id;
    private static int student_id;
}
```

Comment: Can you post more of the Student class? I'm guessing the fields are static...

Comment: The file with your student constructor won't compile, since `class` cannot be used as variable name. And please, don't start variable names with an uppercase character.

Comment: This can't be your real code. You have a variable called `class`.

Comment: Take the word `static` out of your `Student` class.

Comment: @Steven is right.. you are declaring all of your members as static (which means no matter how many Student classes you create, there's only ever one copy of the field)

Comment: what is `Stringinfo` ?

Comment: @Steven they are is that the problem?

Comment: @MCEmperor I'm sorry I had a typo while copying the code. why is it considered bad to start variable names with uppercase characters? I didn't know that...

Comment: @khelwood I had a typo while copying the code, I'm sorry. Thanks for you help!

Comment: @TygerKrash thanks you so much for your help!

Comment: @Squimae219 It's a common coding convention to start variable names with a lower case letter (`class` is a java keyword however and therefore must not be used as identifier), see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: @fabian thanks the link was really useful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static members means that the member belong to the class and not to the object and thus your members keeps on changing.

My guess is your members are static, so try to define your Student class like this:

```
public class Student {

    private int certification_num;
    private int class_id;
    private int average_point;
    private int student_id;
    private int age;
    public Student(int certif, int clazz, int ave, int i, int a)
    {
        this.certification_num = certif;
        this.class_id = clazz;
        this.average_point = ave;
        this.student_id = i;
        this.age = a;
    }
}
```

Comment: That was exactly my problem. thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Take the word `static` out of your `Student` class.

`static` means "one of these for all Students". But every student should have a different age, id etc., so those fields (and associated methods) should not be static.

Comment: Thanks for your help!! I did't know that... :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all I advice you to change your Student class as follow:

```
public class Student
{
  private int certification_num;
  private int class_id;
  private int average_point;
  private int student_id;
  private int age;

  public int getCertification_num() {
    return this.certification_num;
  }
  // Do this for all variables

  public void setCertification_num(int certif) {
    this.certification_num = certif;
  }
  // Do this for all variables
}
```

After that you can easy use your Student class. Also in other situations, when you don't have or need all information.

Fill your Array:

```
ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
for(int i = 1; i < LineCount + 1 ; i++)
{
  String[] temp;
  temp = Stringinfo[i].split(" ");
  Student s = new Student();
  s.setCertification_num(Integer.parseInt(temp[0]);
  //Do for all other fields

  Students.add(s);
}
```